# jQuery Select radio by value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have and HTML radio control:

```
<input id="group" type="radio" value="Canada" name="SpecialTerms"></input>
<input id="group" type="radio" value="USA" name="SpecialTerms"></input>
```

Using jQuery how to I select the Canada radio item where there are other radio's with Canada too?

Comment: `$('input[value="Canada"]')` should do...

Comment: As @Sergio mentions below, IDs **must** be unique. Use a common name attribute to group radio buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this to select the radio that contains `value=Canada`

```
$('input:radio[value="Canada"]').prop('checked', 1);
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/dFKdW/)

**Update :** An `id` must be unique, changed `id` to class, like `class=group`, check the updated fiddle.

**HTML:** (notice different classes with same value)

```
<input class="group" type="radio" value="Canada" name="SpecialTerms"></input>
<input class="group" type="radio" value="USA" name="SpecialTerms"></input>

<input class="Nogroup" type="radio" value="Canada" name="SpecialTerms"></input>
<input class="Nogroup" type="radio" value="USA" name="SpecialTerms"></input>
```

**JS:** (Select/check the radio button with `value=Canada` and has class `group`, the first radio here)

```
$(':radio.group[value="Canada"]').prop('checked', 1);
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/dFKdW/2/)

**Update:** Also, you may try this (with different names but same values)

**HTML:**

```
<input class="group" type="radio" value="Canada" name="SpecialTerms"></input>
<input class="group" type="radio" value="USA" name="SpecialTerms"></input>

<input class="group" type="radio" value="Canada" name="NoSpecialTerms"></input>
<input class="group" type="radio" value="USA" name="NoSpecialTerms"></input>
```

**JS:**

```
$(':radio[name="SpecialTerms"][value="Canada"]').prop('checked', 1);
```

Or

```
$(':radio[name="SpecialTerms"]').filter(function(){
    return this.value == 'Canada';
}).prop('checked', 1);
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/dFKdW/3/)

Answer (score 4):

```
$('input[value=Canada]')
```

should do it.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/F7aZM/)**

BTW, proper syntax for a radio input is `<input id="group" type="radio" value="Canada" name="SpecialTerms" />` (no closing `</input>` tag)

Comment: Missing double quotes `$('input[value="Canada"]')`

Comment: @hitautodestruct, not needed.

Comment: @hitautodestruct - it's not necessary in this case

Comment: @j08691 Neither is a semicolon but it's better to show a proper example.

Comment: @hitautodestruct - it is proper when the value is a single word.

Comment: Oh and @hitautodestruct, as the jQuery documentation states (http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/): "value: An attribute value. Can be either an unquoted single word or a quoted string."

Comment: That's nice. But I'm sure someone is going to come along and try to pick up from your example then waste few hours wondering why multiple values are not working until he spots that tiny line you pointed out in the api.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is:

```
$('input[value="Canada"]')
```

See [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for more information

Answer (score 1):

If there are other radio groups on the page, you would select the one you want like this:

```
$('#group[value="Canada"])
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L5j52/)

***Update***

As mentioned above, the IDs should be unique.  With that in mind, you can use a mutliple attribute selector like this:

```
 $('[name="SpecialTerms"][value="Canada"]')
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L5j52/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$('input:radio[value='Canada']').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: should be using `prop` here

Comment: You should use `.prop()` for ***checked***.